# Mysql LIKE Order Bu Exact Match

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that gets information using the LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$search%'
```

Now if i search for "Hello there" it will return something like

```
Oh hello there
Hello there
Hello there how are you
```

But i want to sort it by exact match first so it should be like

```
Hello there
Hello there how are you
Oh hello there
```

With the exact match on top and the exact match at the start of the sentence after that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column LIKE '%$search%'
    order by case when column like '$search%'  then 1        //hello in begining
                  when column like '%$search%' then 2        //hello in middle
                  when column like '%$search'  then 3 end    //hello in end
```

[watch demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da7549/10)

Comment: Doesn't return anything, hmm

Comment: doesnt return anything? check my answer and look demo

Comment: I did, i changed the hello to my variable and changed the column name and it won't return anything

Comment: be sure to change `$search` in all like , because it should work perfect or you made something wrong.

Comment: Great works thank you

Comment: finaly :). you welcome !

Comment: Why are my results coming in backwards though?

Answer (score 7):

Use [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) to order the result by the position of the search string in the column:;

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '%$search%'
order by INSTR(column, '$search')
```

Comment: Great thanks, is there a way i can have the results after the exact match ordered by if the string begins the sentence, like "hello there you" would be above "you hello there"

Comment: @user2458791: You can use `INSTR()`. See my update.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY column
```

Comment: No gives me same output